# Export from Outlook (not express) - import in Windows Mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-mail

I have Outlook 2003 on an old laptop running XP - and I need to move contacts and mail to a new Vista running Windows Mail.

Windows Mail does not seem to be able to import pst-files.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export to a CSV. Both systems understand those.

Answer (score 0):

Start Outlook Express on the old machine, select to import from Outlook/Exchange to get all email into Outlook Express. Once that's done you copy the Outlook Express data files located at c:\documents and settings\username\Local settings\Identities\GUID\Microsoft\Outlook Express over to your new machine.

On the new machine you start Windows Mail and select Import mail and point to the folder with your Outlook Express data files. Once it's done all of your email should be successfully transfered to the new machine